# Inverting Matrix Equations Y = F(X)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a arbitrary $N \times N$ matrix $S$. I have an function of this matrix given by:

$$A = F(S) = 2S + P^{-1}S + 2SP + PSP$$

where $P$ is the a cyclic permutation matrix which when acting on the left of a matrix sends row $i$ to row $i-1$ (with $0 = N$). For example with $N=3$

$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&1 \\ 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Thus $P^N = I$. I want to invert the above equation to find $ S = F^{-1}(A) $ which I am sure can be done.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this most effectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you "sure" that $F$ has an inverse? In fact, when $N=3$, $F$ has no inverse. To see this, note that $P^{-1}=P^2$ and $P^3=I$. So, if we put $S=P-I$, we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
F(S) &=& 2S + P^{-1}S + 2SP + PSP\\
&=& 2(P-I) + P^{-1}(P-I) + 2(P-I)P + P(P-I)P\\
&=& (2P-2I) + (I-P^{-1}) + (2P^2-2P) + (P^3-P^2)\\
&=& (2P-2I) + (I-P^2) + (2P^2-2P) + (I-P^2) = 0.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
So $F(S)=0$ for some nonzero $S$. Hence $F$ has no inverse.

Comment: yes I have just come to that as well... in fact I now think that it will be non-invertible for any $N$...

Comment: Not exactly. For even $N$, $F$ has no inverse because  $F(uu^T)=0$ when $u^T=(1,-1,1,-1,\ldots,1,-1)$. For odd $N$ between 3 and 27, $F$ is non-invertible only when $N=3,9$, and I have no idea which odd $N$ in general will give rise to an invertible $F$.

Comment: I understand now why my intuition was wrong here, the domain I am interested in is the positive matrices $S_{ij}>0$.

Comment: For even $N$, restricting $S$ to positive definite matrices does not change the conclusion. In my above comment, we have $F(uu^T)=0$. The matrix $uu^T$ is Hermitian but not positive definite. However, for any positive definite matrix $S$, the sum $S+\alpha uu^T$ is positive definite when $\alpha$ is sufficiently small. Since $F(S+\alpha uu^T)=F(S)$, $F$ is still non-invertible.

Comment: I am interested in the positive (non-negative) matrices not the positive definite ones, however I believe that doesn't change the conclusions of the above comment as (like you said) for positive $S$, $S + \alpha uu^{T}$ will still be positive for sufficiently small $\alpha$.